# typescript : determine if 2 lists have at least one common element

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I have 2 lists of integers that are L1 and L2.

L1 and L2 can be of any length (0,1 or many)

I am building a method that must return false if any L1's element is not in L2 and true otherwise :

I am doing this :

```
private myMethod(L1: int[],L2: int[])
{
    return L1.every(L1element => L2.includes(L1element))
}
```

With this code, everything is working well, but I am wondering if I am doing in the most efficient way :
cause for every L1's element (at least the first one and until the last one in the worst case) I am
iterating on every L2's element (at least the first one and until the last one in the worst case), so the
cost if o(L1's length * L2's length) if I am not wrong. Wouldn't be possible to improve the performance
by first sorting the 2 lists or is there any way, I've checked a little bit and some talk about the intersection but I don't know what this intersection is doing under the hood, is it doing the same thing I am doing?

Comment: Note that Javascript doesn't have anything called "lists", but it has arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a Set of `L2` first, and then instead of `.includes` (which is `O(n)`), use `.has` (which is `O(1)`):

```
private myMethod(L1: int[],L2: int[])
{
    const L2Set = new Set(L2);
    return L1.every(L1element => L2Set.has(L1element));
}
```

This decreases the overall complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`.

Comment: ok, but to build L2Set, I think I'll have to iterate once on L2, so my complexity will be o(L2's length) + o(L1's length) if I am correct ? but anyway, it will still reduce my complexity

Comment: Computational complexity is usually presented as the *order of magnitude* of calculations needed, so there's `O(1)`, `O(log n)`, `O(n)`, `O(n ^ 2)`, etc. Figures *other* than the main magnitude often aren't included (eg, `O(4n + 9n)` simplifies to `O(n)`). Yes, this method requires iterating over `L2`, and then over `L1`, but since you want to identify differences, there's no way *other* than to iterate over both arrays at least once.